# Dual Vector Space embedding

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

Is there an embedding of any vector space $V$ into $V^*$?

As far as I know it is not true. The statement that I know of is that there is natural embedding of $V$ into $V^{**}$

Is there any condition/ special vector spaces for which $V$ can be into $V^*$ naturally?

Comment: In the first line you ask for an embedding, in the last line for a natural embedding. These are different questions (and have different answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ has an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, then for each $v\in V$ we can construct an element $f_v\in V^*$ by
$$
f_v(x) = \langle x,v\rangle \quad x\in X.
$$
This yields a natural embedding of $V$ in $V^*$ for inner product spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You have such a thing in spaces with an inner product. A inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$ is an inner product on a vector space $V$ over field $K$, i.e. a map $$
  \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle \,:\, V\times V \to K
$$
that is linear in it's first argument, and either linear or conjugate linear (i.e. $\langle x,\lambda y \rangle = \bar\lambda \langle x,y\rangle $) in it's second argument.

If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is bilinear (respectively conjugate linear in it's second argument), then a linear (respectively conjugate linear) embedding of $V \to V^*$ is given by $$
  \cdot^* \,:\, V \to V^* \,:\, c \mapsto \left(x \mapsto \langle x,c \rangle \right)
$$
If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is bilinear, it's clear that $x^*$ is a linear map $V \to K$ for every $x$, and that $\cdot^*$ is linear as a map $V \to V^*$. For it to be injective, it must hold that $x^*$ is the zero map only if $x$ is the zero vector. This is e.g. the case if $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is positive definite, because then for every non-zero $x$, $x^*(x) = \langle x,y \rangle > 0$. For generally, it suffices for the injectivity of $\cdot^*$ that for every $x$ there is an $y$ with $\langle x,y \rangle \neq 0$. If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is no bilinear, but rather conjugate linear in it's second argument, then the construction above yields a conjugate linear map $V \to V^*$.

Conversely, if you have an embedding $\cdot^* \,:V \to V^*$, you can define an inner product by $$
  \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle \,:\, V\times V \to K \,:\, \langle x,y \rangle = y^*(x) \text{.}
$$
Note, however, that in the general case this inner product might not be positive definite, and not (conjugate) symmetric.

---

If we drop all pretense of *naturality*, talk pure vector spaces only, i.e. $V^*$ means the *algebraic* dual of $V$, and assume the axiom of choice (AC), we can do the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$, and $B$ be a basis of $V$ - the existence of which is guaranteed by AC. Then, by the very definition of vector space basis, there's a *coordinatization map* $$
  \mathfrak{C}_B \,:\, V \to K^B \,:\, x \mapsto (x_b)_{b \in B}
$$
such that for all $x \in V$ only *finitely* many $x_b \neq 0$ and $$
  x = \sum_{b \in B} x_b b \text{.}
$$
Note that $\mathfrak{C}_B$ is *linear*, if we interpret sums and products on $K^B$ *pointwise*, i.e. we have that $\left(\mathfrak{C}_B(x+y)\right)_b = \left(\mathfrak{C}_B(x)\right)_b + \left(\mathfrak{C}_B(y)\right)_b$ and also $\left(\mathfrak{C}_B(\lambda x)\right)_b = \lambda\left(\mathfrak{C}_B(x)\right)_b$ for all $b \in B$.

We can now define a inner product on $V$ just as we do in the finite-dimensional case, i.e. set $$
  \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle \,:\, V\times V \to K \,:\, \langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{b \in B} x_b \overline{y_b}
  \quad\text{where $(x_b)_{b \in B} = \mathfrak{C}_B(x)$ and $(y_b)_{b \in B} = \mathfrak{C}_B(y)$.}
$$
(If the underlying field is not $\mathbb{C}$, replace $\overline{y_b}$ with just $y_b$). That sum is well-defined because if only finitely many $x_b\neq 0$ and $y_b \neq 0$, then also only finitely many summands $x_by_b \neq 0$. The linearity of $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ in both argument follows from the linearity of $\mathfrak{C}_B$. If the underlying field $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ this inner product is positive definite, because then for $x \neq 0$ you have $\sum_{b\in B} x_b\overline{x_b} = \sum_{b \in B} |x_b|^2 > 0$. If, on the other hand, $K = \textrm{GF}(p^n)$, then $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$ if $x = b_1 + \ldots b_n$ for $n$ distinct $b_1,\ldots,b_n \in B$.

And now, just as above, we have an embedding $V \to V^*$, defined by $$
  \cdot^* \,:\, V \to V^* \,:\, c \mapsto \left(x \mapsto \langle x,c \rangle \right)
$$
If $x \in V$, $x \neq 0$ and $(x_b)_{b \in B} = \mathfrak{C}_B(x)$ is the coordinatization of $x$, then $x_{b} \neq 0$ for some $b$. Then $x^*(b) = x_b \neq 0$, i.e for every non-zero vector $x$, $x^*$ is *not* the zero map, which proves that $\cdot^*$ is injective (even if the inner product was *not* positive definite).

Comment: if it is not inner product space, is it ever (not necessarily naturally) possible to find a basis for $V$, such that there exists an embedding? More precisely, is it possible to define a basis of $Hom(U,V)$ such that there exists embedding of $Hom(U,V)$ into $Hom(U,V)^*$. I am repeating(perhaps) this, as I was assigned this as homework and I can't see how.

Comment: You'll have to define exactly what you require of an *embedding*. If you assume the axiom of choice, both $V$ and $V^*$ have a basis, say $B$ and $B^*$. If these have the same cardinality, there's always a linear bijection $V \to V^*$, and if $|B| \leq |B^*|$ there's always a linear injection $V \to V^*$. But these are, in general, very far from "natural", I'd say.

Comment: I believe naturally, embedding (in context of vector spaces) would be injective linear map.

Comment: @user143774 I've extended my answer to show that such an embedding always exists if you assume the axiom of choice. Note, however, that this construction is hightly non-constructive because you usually *don't* know much about a basis other than that it exists. In particular, that embedding *won't* usually be compatible with any additional structure you have on $V$ like a norm or a topology.

Comment: When you say "It's clear that $⋅^∗$ is linear", I would say that this is only clear if you take the "inner product" to be bilinear (but then in the complex setting is is not an inner product); if instead it is _conjugate-linear_ in its second argument, then the map $⋅^∗$ would seem to be conjugate-linear too.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen True. Edited the answer to say that. I'm not sure if you can always constructively define linear embedding if the inner product is hermitian. It seems one would essentially need to define a conjugate linear map $\bar\cdot \,:\, V \to V$ for that. Such a map obviously exists if one assumes $V$ has a basis, but how one would define it without that assumption I don't currently see. Maybe some algebraic trickery works, though, I dunno.